# Need help in proving a version of Stirling Formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, integral-inequality

I am trying to prove this inequality but unable to do so ->

$log(n!) \leq \int_2^{n+1} log(x) dx $ .

My attempt -> using Stirling Formula LHS = n log(n) - n + O ( log(n) ) and Integral is n( log(n+1) ) + log( n+1) - n +1-2log 2 .

But I am unable to think now on how to prove that RHS is greater than Or equal to LHS.

Comment: @T.S Ok, will keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\log n! = \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\log k}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\int_k^{k + 1} {\log xdx} }  = \int_2^{n + 1} {\log xdx} 
$$

Comment: How did you proved log(k) $\leq \int_k^{k+1} { log(x) } $ ? It's not trivial verification

Comment: @YannicMuller $\log(k)=\int_{k}^{k+1} \log(k) dx$ (note the integrand is $\log(k)$ here, not $\log(x)$. Now, can you see how to get the inequality $\log(k)\le\int_{k}^{k+1} \log(x) dx$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's formula is not useful. Note that $\int_2^{3} \log x dx>\log 2$, $\int_3^{4} \log x dx>\log 3$, ...,$\int_n^{n+1} \log x dx>\log n$. Just add these inequalities.

Comment: How did you proved log(k) $\leq \int_k^{k+1} { log(x) } $ ? It's not trivial verification. Also you are assuming this to hold for all integers greater than or equal to 2 .  I think it's better if it is proved. Not all people know this for example me.

Comment: @YannicMuller $\log $ is an increasing function. So $\log x \geq \log k$ on $(k, k+1)$. Hence $\int_k^{k+1} \log x dx \geq \int_k^{k+1}  \log k dx =\log k$.

Comment: thanks a lot , I can accept only 1 answer.